# Is it possible to force an application to connect to Internet via specific allowed UDP port?

Tags: linux, networking, port

If I execute :

```
netstat -tulpn
```

On an cachy (Arch derivative) distro, I find:

```
Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process 

info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see  it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::27500                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:47435           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           94940/vivaldi-bin   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::44439                :::*                                402026/firefox      
udp6       0      0 :::45040                :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::49550                :::*                                402026/firefox      
udp6       0      0 :::50429                :::*                                402026/firefox      
udp6       0      0 :::53286                :::*                                402026/firefox      
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::55966                :::*                                402026/firefox      
udp6       0      0 :::56350
```

So Firefox is listening to random UDP ports. I read that firefox establishes ports as chosen by itself to connect to the internet.

Is there a simple way, on Linux, that I can force a selected list of applications to use a selected list of ports [possibly using a local Proxy server on a small raspberry Pi or otherwise]?

More specifically, I want a text file `port.txt` to have certain ports listed in it, such as 1234, 5678, 0987, 6543 ... or a range like 1234 - 5678

In another file `app.txt`, I want a list of applications, such as firefox, vivaldi, evilCorporation.secretStuff, seattleStarBucks_worlDomination ... But these applications, when they request the OS for a port, only be allowed to communicate to the internet through a port mentioned in `port.txt`.

The idea is, any other application, trying to access the internet, will be immediately recognized, and an alert be raised.

Thank you.

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem. The real problem you're trying to solve seems to be, "How can I be alerted if unauthorized apps or processes try to connect to the Internet?", which might be easily solvable. But unfortunately instead of asking that question, you came up with a half-baked idea that might not work out, and asked for help with the half-baked idea that might not be a good approach at all.

Comment: Not just unauthorized apps, I want a method to force all outgoing connections to go through a list of allowed ports as well.

Comment: Okay, but what purpose is that solving? There are probably better solutions to whatever it is you're trying to solve with this port-forcing stuff.